# Make a screenshot every page of PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

How can I make a screenshot from **every page** of PDF file and save result as images in PHP? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the "make a screenshot" can be replaced for your purpose by "create a raster image" for each PDF page?

In this case you could use ImageMagick and/or one of its PHP-enabled libraries. Here is a command line representation:

```
 convert some.pdf[15-19] some.png
```

This will convert not all pages, but the page range 16--20 (page counting here is zero-based (not intuitive, I know...). To convert all pages, just skip the `[15-19]` part.

The output PNG names will be `some-0.png`, `some-1.png`, ... `some-4.png`.

To create JPEG or GIF instead of PNG, simply use one of these:

```
 convert some.pdf[15-19] some.jpg
 convert some.pdf[15-19] some.gif
```

By default ImageMagick will use a resolution of 72 PPI. This will indirectly determine the image dimensions of the PNG/JPEG/GIF output. Should you need other output dimensions than the defaults, you have different options, for example:

1. either add `-density`
2. or add `-resize`

to the command line:

```
convert -density 200 some.pdf some.png

convert some.pdf -resize 50% some.png
```